# Querying data from sqlthrough java`

Tags: java, mysql

I have two sql tables containing details of students currently studying and passed out. Through a jsp i want to search details of the students.  Currently what i am doing is run two separate select statements on both the tables to fetch data from these tables. Is dere a better way to do it. I am sing java as backend.

Comment: if the tables are related then you can do 1 query with a join. please post more details for help.

Comment: tables are not related in any ways both the tables have different student ids

Comment: there is nothing wrong with running 2 statements.

Comment: Provide the column names of two tables separately  and columns names that you want to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and the best way I found is querying 2 times.

But in your case, if you looking for the similar properties of the students you can do something like "base table", I mean add a new table called 'student'

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `idstudent` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `etc.` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idstudent`)
)
```

and then you can add your tables for students currently studying and passed out containing their specific data. Such that they have a foreign key referencing the `student` table. And now you can query on the base table and get the common data.

In case you need the specific data for the two types of students you still need run more queries. Hope it was helpful in your case.